# Assign a value to each element of a matrix inside a given region in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have an y*x matrix in matlab, and I want to assign a value to any point of the region of the matrix between 4 points, like A,B,C,D the image of which I know the coordinates, if the point were aligned this wouldn't be a problem, but they aren't.

Is there a function to do this ?

[image: Example of result]

**Edit**

I have an an input matrix of numbers between 0 and 1.
The size of the matrix is 720*1280
The region is defined like this

x = [3 10  27 20 3];
y = [10 40 31 1  10];

It doesn't matter too much if the pixels are excluded or included along the edge of the rectangle, but is better if they are included.

The output matrix should be equal to the input matrix but with the values of the points inside the region of interest replaced by some other value, for example 2.

The solution I was searching for is very similar to the one that m7913d gave me.

Comment: Provide sample input/s and output matrices

Comment: Mask the polygon, assign to the masked matrix. If you provide a proper question, I would be happy to provide an answer. For one thing, you need to determine how you decide which pixels are going to be included vs excluded along the edge of that rectangle. That is not something I can do for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`poly2mask`](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/poly2mask.html) to convert the polygon to a mask and then change the desired elements in the matrix using [logical indexing](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) as follows:

```
% Create a sample matrix
matrix = rand(50, 50);

% Define your region as a polygon
x = [3 10  27 20 3];
y = [10 40 31 1  10];

% Convert the polygon to a mask
mask = poly2mask(x,y,size(matrix, 1),size(matrix, 2));

% Change the elements in matrix which are inside the polygon
matrix(mask) = 123;

% Display the result
figure
imshow(matrix, 'InitialMagnification', 'fit')
hold on
plot(x, y, 'r')
```

[image]